# Pushing data from Angular Bootstrap Typeahead into another tab using UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-typeahead, angular-ui-tabset

I have 3 tabs: customers, billing, and method. On the first tab I have the Bootstrap Typeahead, that is connected to a json file of customers. The second tab is a detailed view of the customer account with outstanding charges. Finally, the third tab is to actually charge the customer with a credit card. Additionally, I am using UI Router to navigate through a complex hierarchy. the tabs are named views of a page called make-payments, which is a child of a parent state called payments. I am trying to use the typeahead in the first tab (customers) to select and view a customer detail in the second tab (billing). I am hoping this happens when the user selects the person from the dropdown, they should immediately navigate to the next tab, and the next tab should show that persons details. I am having some difficulty really understanding how to get the data from the typeahead to the next two tabs, and if I need a service to do this or not.

make-payment.html(My tabs):

```html
<h3 class="text-center">Make a One-Time Payment</h3>
<uib-tabset type="pills nav-pills-centered">

  <uib-tab heading="1">
    <div ui-view=customers></div>
  </uib-tab>

  <uib-tab heading="2">
    <div ui-view=billing></div>
  </uib-tab>

  <uib-tab heading="3">
    <div ui-view=method></div>
  </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

customers.html & the typeahead.js ctrl:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('TypeAheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('customers.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.customers = data;
    });

    var self = this;
    self.submit1 = function() {
      console.log('First form submit with', self.customer)
    };


  });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="TypeAheadCtrl as ctrl">
  <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit1()" name="customerForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="account">Account Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search or enter an account number" ng-model="ctrl.customer.account" uib-typeahead="customer as customer.index for customer in customers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:6" typeahead-template-url="templates/customer-tpl.html"
      typeahead-no-results="noResults">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

app.js (where I have ui-router stuff)

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/payments/make-payment');

      $stateProvider

      // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('payments', {
        url: '/payments',
        templateUrl: 'views/payments.html'
      })

      .state('activity', {
          url: '/activity',
          templateUrl: 'views/activity.html'
        })
        // nested lists
        .state('payments.make-payment', {
          url: '/make-payment',
          views: {
            '': {
              templateUrl: 'views/make-payment.html'
            },
            'customers@payments.make-payment': {
              templateUrl: 'views/customers.html'
            },
            'billing@payments.make-payment': {
              templateUrl: 'views/billing.html'
            },
            'method@payments.make-payment': {
              templateUrl: 'views/method.html'

            });

        });
```

billing.html

```html
<p>{{ctrl.customer.account.name}}</p>
<p>{{ctrl.customer.account.address}}</p>
<p>{{ctrl.customer.account.email}}</p>
<p>{{ctrl.customer.account.phone}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send the selected customer data to a service and pull from the service in the two tabs.

so I guess when you actually select a user from the dropdown or whatever you can call myFactory.setCustomer(data).

and in your other two states you can watch the getCustomer() function in myFactory

```
.factory('myFactory', myFactory);
    function myFactory() {
        var customer;
        function setCustomer(data) {
            customer = data;
        }
        function getCustomer() {
            return customer;
        }

        //public API
        return {
            setCustomer: setCustomer,
            getCustomer: getCustomer
        }
    }
```